# Помогите понять потенциальный bug, навязаный утилитой Findbugs. Мутирующие объекты в set() методе

Tags: java, intellij-idea

При написании кода я использую утилиту FindBugs, для поиска потенциальных багов.

Допустип у меня есть класс :

```
public class Line<T> implements Serializable, Cloneable {

private T[] pointsOnLine;

private T valueMinPoint;
private T valueMaxPoint;

public Line() {
}

public Line(T[] pointsOnLine) {
    this.pointsOnLine = pointsOnLine;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Line)) return false;

    Line<?> line = (Line<?>) o;

    // Probably incorrect - comparing Object[] arrays with Arrays.equals
    if (!Arrays.equals(getPointsOnLine(), line.getPointsOnLine())) return false;
    if (getValueMinPoint() != null ? !getValueMinPoint().equals(line.getValueMinPoint()) : line.getValueMinPoint() != null)
        return false;
    return getValueMaxPoint() != null ? getValueMaxPoint().equals(line.getValueMaxPoint()) : line.getValueMaxPoint() == null;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = Arrays.hashCode(pointsOnLine);
    result = 31 * result + (valueMaxPoint != null ? valueMaxPoint.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (valueMinPoint != null ? valueMinPoint.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Line[" +
            "pointsOnLine=" + Arrays.toString(pointsOnLine) +
            ", valueMaxPoint=" + valueMaxPoint +
            ", valueMinPoint=" + valueMinPoint +
            ']';
}

@Override
protected Line<T> clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Line<T> line = (Line<T>) super.clone();
    line.setValueMinPoint(this.getValueMinPoint());
    line.setValueMaxPoint(this.getValueMaxPoint());
    line.setPointsOnLine(this.getPointsOnLine());
    return line;
}

public T[] getPointsOnLine() {
    return pointsOnLine;
}

public void setPointsOnLine(T[] pointsOnLine) {
    this.pointsOnLine = pointsOnLine;
}

public T getValueMinPoint() {
    return valueMinPoint;
}

public void setValueMinPoint(T valueMinPoint) {
    this.valueMinPoint = valueMinPoint;
}

public T getValueMaxPoint() {
    return valueMaxPoint;
}

public void setValueMaxPoint(T valueMaxPoint) {
    this.valueMaxPoint = valueMaxPoint;
}

}
```

*Проверку корректности переданного аргумента в setter, я еще не успел добавить.*

При проверки кода утилитой, она ругнулась мне на методы setPointsOnLine() и на getPointsOnLine(). А также и на конструктор.

А именно :

> EI: May expose internal representation by returning reference to mutable object (EI_EXPOSE_REP)

Returning a reference to a mutable object value stored in one of the object's fields exposes the internal representation of the object.  If instances are accessed by untrusted code, and unchecked changes to the mutable object would compromise security or other important properties, you will need to do something different. Returning a new copy of the object is better approach in many situations.

Здесь говорится о том, что объект которому присвается значение объекта переданного аргументом в setter, является mutable и может быть изменен из любого участка кода.

Я понимаю как исправить потенциальный баг, допустим :

```
public void setPointsOnLine(T[] pointsOnLine) {
    this.pointsOnLine = new Line<>(pointsOnLine).getPointsOnLine();
}
```

Но я не понимаю, почему это так работает и как же такое код писать в дальнейшем в других классах? 
Неужели если полем класса является ссылочная переменная, то всегда писать такой код в setter-ах? 
И что имеется ввиду, что этот объект mutable? Тоесть, если я уберу getter, то объект будет immutable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это предупреждение сообщает, что вызывающий код обладает ссылкой на изменяемый объект в приватном поле вашего объекта. Вы получили ссылку на изменяемый объект извне (в конструкторе и сеттере) или отдали ее (в геттере). Таким образом вызывающий код может неожиданно для вас поменять состояние части вашего объекта и таким образом обойти проверки, которые вы могли бы проводить в конструкторе или сеттере.

Например можно даже без использования сеттеров изменить содержимое вашего `Line`:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Integer[] points = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4};

    Line line1 = new Line(points);

    System.out.println( "line1 = " + line1 );
    // line1 = Line[pointsOnLine=[1, 2, 3, 4], valueMaxPoint=null, valueMinPoint=null]

    // ну не создавать же каждый раз новый массив
    points[0] = 5; points[3] = 7;

    Line line2 = new Line(points);
    System.out.println( "line2 = " + line2 );
    // line2 = Line[pointsOnLine=[5, 2, 3, 7], valueMaxPoint=null, valueMinPoint=null]

    System.out.println( "line1 === line2 ? " + line1.equals(line2) );
    // line1 === line2 ? true

    // Внезапно
    System.out.println( "line1 = " + line1 );
    // line1 = Line[pointsOnLine=[5, 2, 3, 7], valueMaxPoint=null, valueMinPoint=null]
}
```

Лучшим решением было бы использовать неизменяемые объекты в качестве параметров и возвращаемых значений. Если это невозможно, нужно создавать защитные копии (defensive copy). Копия должна быть глубокой, т.е. если ваш массив содержит изменяемые объекты, каждый объект тоже должен быть скопирован. Для массивов примитивов или неизменяемых объектов подойдет `clone()` или `Arrays.copyOf`.

Предложенный вами способ проблему не решает, т.к. ссылка на массив просто прогоняется через конструктор и геттер без изменений.

Подробнее см. "Effective Java" Item 39.

Comment: Судя по Вашему примеру получается, что оба объекта Line, содержат в себе ссылку (ссылаются) на один и тот же массив. Я все понял. Огромное спасибо.